# How to create a new ms chart based on another chart in code?

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

How to create a new chart based on another chart in code?

There is a chart has been set appearance ,I want create a new chart with the same appearance and different datasource.How can I do this in .cs file?

Comment: do  you want to show two charts on same page on on different page .. or  you can just change datasource for first chart for creating new chart ...

Answer (score 0):

the usual: declare a function that returns a new chart object with the desired appearance and after getting a chart object form it, bind it to a data-source